# Apache folder not showing up

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

I'm having trouble with installing a Laravel 4 app on a hosted environment.

The problem I'm having at the moment is that the "public" folder is not showing in the listing when going to [www.eversite.be/laravel/](http://eversite.be/laravel/), can someone tell me why that is, and how can I make it visible.

Does this have something to do with Apache, for instance, a permission setting? That would be strange though since I already changed the folder to 777.

Apache error log:

```
[Mon Jan 13 17:47:11 2014] [alert] [client 178.116.245.86] /sites/eversite.be/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Mon Jan 13 17:47:19 2014] [alert] [client 178.116.245.86] /sites/eversite.be/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Mon Jan 13 17:47:23 2014] [alert] [client 178.116.245.86] /sites/eversite.be/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

.htaccess file in /public/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

A link to phpinfo(); : http://eversite.be/laravel/modrewrite.php

Comment: I removed `<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>` and fixed the problem.hope its help to you.

Answer (score 1):

In your update, it seems that the path to your files is not correct. If I'm not mistaken, **__*DIR*__** may not be available in PHP 5.2, which is the version that you are using. Use instead:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since opening `http://eversite.be/laravel/public` triggers a 500 Internal Server Error, I'd say that you have an invalid setting in `public/.htaccess`. You now need to inspect the server logs to find the real error message.

Comment: These are the error's i'm receiving: [Mon Jan 13 17:47:19 2014] [alert] [client 178.116.245.86] /sites/eversite.be/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Mon Jan 13 17:47:23 2014] [alert] [client 178.116.245.86] /sites/eversite.be/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
[Mon Jan 13 17:47:26 2014] [alert] [client 178.116.245.86] /sites/eversite.be/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Comment: And this is the .htaccess file: 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: If you need to added further info I suggest you edit the question—code in comments is unreadable. Whatever `Options not allowed here` means exactly that: you're not allowed to use the `Options` directive. If it's a shared server, you can ask whether you can be granted permission.