# Internal server error when set up Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make a site using Laravel. When I put Laravel to "www" folder and browse

> localhost/laravel/public
>   then I get a internal server error.

In error log display the following message.

> /var/www/laravel/public/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

before put a post I saw similar problem here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097240/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097240/apache-folder-not-showing-up) and I didn't see any solution.

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a .htaccess file in the directory `/var/www/laravel/public` with an `Options` directive in the wrong place.

You can only use the `Options` directive in a `<directory>` block.

You need to remove it, move it to the correct place or otherwise edit the file to correct the error.

See the Apache reference [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)

Comment: Thank you.I removed options from there.

Comment: That is pretty understandable but I am confused that the same .htacess had been working fine on Ubuntu but now causing 500 error on Arch linux.